# How to pass the event.target.value from one component to another component using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have below Simple Dropdown component

```
import React,{Fragment} from 'react';

export default class SimpleDropdown extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            listOpen: false,            
            selectedValue: 'calculated Measure'
        }
        this.selectedItem = this.selectedItem.bind(this);
    }

    selectedItem = (event)=> {        
      this.setState({
           selectedValue: event.target.value
      })           
    }   

    render() {
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <select className="dd-wrapper" value={this.state.selectedValue} onSelect={this.selectedItem} >
                    {this.props.list.map((item) => (
                        <option className="dd-list-item" key={item.name} value={item.name}>{item.name}</option>)
                    )}
                </select>
            </Fragment>    
        );
    }
}
```

I'm using this component in some other file as and its state as

```
this.state = {
 measures: [{
                name: 'calculated Measure',
            },{
                name: 'Base Measure'
            }]
 }

<SimpleDropdown title="create Measure" list={this.state.measures} />
```

Now, I want to pass the selected value from simple dropdown component to here, How can I do that?

Comment: Instead of having your `selectedItem` function inside of the `SimpleDropdown` component, define it in your other component and pass it into `SimpleDropdown` as a prop and use that function in your `onSelect`.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is to create your `selectedItem` function from the component you want the value in. Pass that function as a prop to your dropdown as a handler and update the value in the component where you need that value. Notice below `onSelect` is now calling `this.props.handleSelect`.

```
import React,{Fragment} from 'react';

export default class SimpleDropdown extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            listOpen: false,                
        }
    }    

    render() {
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <select className="dd-wrapper" value={this.state.selectedValue} onSelect={this.props.handleSelect} >
                    {this.props.list.map((item) => (
                        <option className="dd-list-item" key={item.name} value={item.name}>{item.name}</option>)
                    )}
                </select>
            </Fragment>    


        );
    }
}
```

I created another component class based on what you posted above to help clarify. But this is where you will define the function and pass it into `SimpleDropdown`.

```
export class TestComponent extends React.Component {
   state = {
       selectedDropDownValue: '',
       [{
           name: 'calculated Measure',
        },
        {
           name: 'Base Measure'
        }
      ]
   }

   handleDropDownSelect = (event) => {
      this.setState({ selectedDropDownValue: event.target.value });
   }

   render() {
      return <SimpleDropdown 
               title="create Measure" 
               list={this.state.measures}
               handleSelect={this.handleDropDownSelect}
             />
   }
}
```

Hopefully this helped! Let me know if you need any more clarification.